# Bash function not executing the input command

Tags: bash, bash-function

In a bash file `s.sh`, I have an Executor function to which I pass the commands to be executed. Whenever some command does not work as expected, this function outputs the command.

```
Executor()
{
    if ! $*
    then
        echo "$*"
        exit 2
    fi
}
```

Now I am invoking this function -

`Executor clangPath="Hello" make` (This is used to set the value of clangPath variable as "Hello" in the makefile)

This caused an error -

```
./s.sh: line 5: clangPath=Hello: command not found
[./s.sh] Error: clangPath=Hello make
```

However executing the same command like this works fine

```
if ! clangPath="Hello" make
then
    echo "HelloWorld!"
fi
```

After looking at the error, I thought there might be a mistake with the string quotations, so I tried

`exitIfFail clangPath='"Hello"' make`

Even this resulted in an error -

```
./s.sh: line 5: clangPath="Hello": command not found
[./s.sh] Error: clangPath="Hello" make
```

What could be the reason for the error?

Comment: You could try if ! /usr/bin/ksh $*  ... depending on where & what shell you're using?  I dont have the ability to test here.

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Eww, `$*`...  I think you misspelt `"$@"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose of the function is to execute some Bash expression, then print an error message, if the expression failed (returned non-zero status), then, there is a way to implement this via `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash -

function Executor()
{
  eval "$@"

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo >&2 "Failed to execute command: $@"
    exit 2
  fi
}
```

The `$?` variable holds the exit status of the previously executed command. So we check if it is non-zero.

Also note how we redirect the error message to the standard error descriptor.

Usage:

```
Executor ls -lh /tmp/unknown-something
ls: cannot access /tmp/unknown-something: No such file or directory
Failed to execute command: ls -lh /tmp/unknown-something


Executor ls -lh /tmp
# some file listing here...
```

The `$@` variable is more appropriate here, as `eval` interprets things itself. See [`$*` and `$@`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF).

Comment: What's with the [`test $?` anti-pattern](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd.3B_.28.28_.21_.24.3F_.29.29_.7C.7C_die)?  A simple `if ! eval "$@"` would be shorter, clearer, and more consistent with the question, and `eval "$@" && return` is simpler still.

Comment: @TobySpeight, it's a matter of preference. Some may think of it as an anti-pattern. But the style used in the answer looks pretty clear to me.